# Transfering Binary data using http requests

Tags: python, http, python-requests, base64

I am trying to transfer files such as jpg images by splitting up the files into chunks and then sending them via http get or post requests to another server where I try to assemble the files back together. For decoding I use pythons `base64` module. Here is the client application:

```
import requests
import base64

URL = "http://10.0.2.5:8080/index.php"

export_file = open("C:\\Users\zarathustra\\Desktop\\cat.jpg", "rb")

while True:
    export_data = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(export_file.read(1024))
    if export_data:
        parameter = {"data" : export_data}
        r = requests.get(url = URL, params=parameter)
    else:
        print ("File transmitted.")
        break
```

And here's the application that receives the data:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import base64

class my_Request_Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def _set_response(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):

        output_file = open("/home/zarathustra/exfiltration.txt", "a")
        output_file.write(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(self.path[16:]))
        output_file.close()

        self._set_response()
        self.wfile.write("GET request for {}".format(self.path).encode('utf-8'))
```

I use another script to reassemble the data:

```
import base64

file = open("/home/zarathustra/exfiltration.txt", "r")
data = file.read()
data2 = base64.b64decode(file.read())
file2 = open("/home/zarathustra/Katze.jpg", "wb")
file2.write(data2)

file.close()
file2.close()
```

The receiving app throws the following error:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('10.0.2.15', 51475)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 316, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 347, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/server.py", line 426, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/server.py", line 414, in handle_one_request
    method()
    print(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(self.path[16:]))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/base64.py", line 133, in urlsafe_b64decode
    return b64decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/base64.py", line 87, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

---

I researched the incorrect padding error using stackoverflow and tried some variations, but could not come up with a working solution. Also I'm not sure if my appproach for splitting/decoding and reassembling is correct. Any suggestions?

Comment: Base-64 encoding involves translating every 3 bytes of data into 4 bytes for transmission. But you are splitting your original data into chunks of 1024 bytes, and 1024 is not a multiple of 3. So at the end of every chunk you are adding two bytes of padding and transmitting 1368 bytes. Are you taking care to reassemble your data without the padding?

Comment: Your question does not include the code in the receiving app (`HTTP_Server2.py`) which is causing the `binascii.Error`, which makes it difficult to provide concrete suggestions.